# why use http.route() method use type="json" in openerp

Tags: json, odoo

**above code from the `website_mail` module controller file `email_designer.py` file**

class WebsiteEmailDesigner(http.Controller):

```
@http.route('/website_mail/email_designer/<model("email.template"):template>/', type='http', auth="user", website=True, multilang=True)
def index(self, template, **kw):
    values = {
        'template': template,
    }

    return request.website.render("website_mail.designer_index", values)

@http.route(['/website_mail/snippets'], type='json', auth="user", website=True)
def snippets(self):
    return request.website._render('website_mail.email_designer_snippets')
```

**which situation we are using `type="json"` and `type="http"` and why..??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them are about communication between client and server. HttpRequest communicates trough the well known GET and POST methods. That means the following:

- The client send a request encoded in the url (GET method) or in the http body (POST method)
- The server returns an object corresponding to the request. Could be an html page, PNG image, CSS file, JavaScript, XML encoded data or whatever.

JsonRequest is an implementation of another protocol for client/server communication - JSON-RPC 2.0. You may want lo took [here](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) form more information. It's a remote procedure call  (RPC) protocol which means that it allows the client to initiate the execution of some method on the server passing some arguments to this method. In response the client gets some data as a result of the method invocation.

EDIT - some more words about the decorators @openerpweb.jsonrequest and @openerpweb.httprequest

Some methods are decorated with the @openerpweb.jsonrequest decorator, other methods - with the @openerpweb.httprequest. This means nothing else but that the first group of methods will be available for execution trough the JSON RPC protocol and the second group will be accessible trough the pure HTTP protocol.

Now, what is the difference? I do we need both jsonrequest and httprequest? Let simplify it like this: JSON is more suitable for executing methods on the server and obtain results. HTTP is simpler and easier to use when all we what is to access some resource on the server.

Let's 'decorate' this with some examples for clarity. Take a look at the following method of the web.controllers.main.Export class:

```
@openerpweb.jsonrequest
def formats(self, req):
    """ Returns all valid export formats

    :returns: for each export format, a pair of identifier and printable name
    :rtype: [(str, str)]
    """
    ...
```

This method accepts some arguments and returns a list (Python list object) containing all known export formats. It will be called in a programmatic way in some python code on the client side.

On the other side are the 'http' methods - like the method css() of the web.controllers.main.Web class:

```
@openerpweb.httprequest
def css(self, req, mods=None):
    ....
```

All this method does is to return a CSS file to the client. It's a simple action like accessing an image, a HTML web page or whatever other resource on the server. The resource we are returning here is nothing complicated as a Python list as in the previous example. We don't need a special format to encode it additionally. So we don't need additional data encoding format as JSON and remote procedure call protocol as JSON RPC.

**type="json":**

it will call JSONRPC as an argument to http.route() so here , there will be only JSON data be able to pass via JSONRPC, It will only accept json data object as argument.

**type="http":**

As compred to JSON, http will pass http request arguments to http.route() not json data.
Examples

```
@http.route('demo_html', type="http") // Work Pefrect when I call this URL
def some_html(self):
    return "<h1>This is a test</h1>"

@http.route('demo_json', type="json") // Not working when I call this URL
def some_json(self):
    return {"sample_dictionary": "This is a sample JSON dictionary"}
```

Comment: I had got that one before but finally thanks Jainik ..!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically type="json" is used to pass data from controller where as type="html" is for responding over http request.

For example from your above code:
 the url "/website_mail/email_designer//" will respond towards any particular http request and route to its web page where as the url "/website_mail/snippets" will just pass json data to its rendered template but there is no physical webpage related to this url.

Answer (score 2):

Methods that received JSON can be defined by passing 'json' to the type argument of http.route(). The OpenERP Javascript client can contact these methods using the JSON-RPC protocol. JSON methods must return JSON. Like the HTTP methods they receive arguments as named parameters (except these arguments are JSON-RPC parameters).

```
@http.route('/division', type="json")
def division(self, i, j):
    return i / j # returns a number
```